# logs multiple servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging

we have set of load balanced j2ee servers where each server generates logs of  >500 MB per day. what is the best way to maintain the logs from the servers.

Currently I have three options.

1. maintain a separate log folder in each serve
2. write the logs to database
3. maintain a separate log server and write the logs using jms

which is best optimal solution for this problem.

Please suggest if you have any more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

An optimal solution can be subjective and it really can depend on what you are trying to achieve with logging and how your environment is set up. First I would like to say that with either solution you choose, logging is not free, so always think about the cost/impact it will have on the system.

Separate folders per server:

- If you use round robin as your load balancing strategy then ever request from the client can be logged on different servers. Trying to collate data log entries across multiple servers is much more difficult.

Write to database:

- This will keep things centralized
- The database access control can be leveraged to give access to the logs.
- With lots of writing, it can put a lot of load on the database causing contention if you have a lot of concurrent usage.

Push into JMS queue:

- I think this is the most flexible option and a good base to build on.
- Allows you to offload the work to another server and you can take a little more time to parse the log for filtering in the future.
- Can maintain a central location for all logs
- Allows you to abstract the persistence mechanism from the process of logging. This means you can log to a database, file system, NoSQL DB, or what every store you would like.
- I would try to minimize what is being logged to the queue instead of filtering what comes out of the queue, so use an appropriate logging level before the queue.